# Qualified name lookup in the name

Tags: c++, namespaces, qualified-name

I want to understand the namespace qualified name lookup rule. I'm trying to do that on the example:

```
namespace A
{
    int a=::b; //error: ‘::b’ has not been declared
}
int b=6;
```

There is a quote which I rely in my reasoning (3.4.3.2/2 N3797):

> For a namespace X and name m, the namespace-qualified lookup set S(X,
>   m) is defined as follows: Let S (X, m) be the **set of all declarations
>   of m in X** and the inline namespace set of X (7.3.1). If S (X, m) is
>   not empty, S(X, m) is S (X, m); otherwise, S(X, m) is the union of
>   S(Ni , m) for all namespaces Ni nominated by using-directives in X and
>   its inline namespace set.

Let `X` be a global scope. We have that `S(X,b)={int b=6}`. This implies that name lookup must be success. But in fact, the program is ill-formed. Might I don't understood this rule correctly?

Comment: The catch is literally in the text that you bolded. The name lookup *is* a success. However, `b` hasn't yet been added to the "set of all declarations in the global namespace".

Comment: @Lilshieste But we can use a class data member inside a member function definition appeared before actual data member declaration.

Comment: But that is an issue of scope; not name lookup. (And 3.3.7/1 is what provides that capability for class types.)

Comment: @Lilshieste I don't agree because unqualified name lookup described as it is corresponding to the member's class scope. This concepts are interrelated (not formally).

Comment: 3.4.1/1 mentions that "the scopes are searched for a declaration...". For class scope, order of declaration doesn't matter, per 3.3.7/1. For global scope, order of declaration *does* matter. But in both cases, declaration **must** occur before name lookup.

Answer (score 0):

b is in global scope but it must be declare before where you are using it.
like

```
int b=6;
namespace A
{
    int a=::b; 
}
```

`(N 3690 Draft)
3.4.1 Unqualified name lookup
4. A name used in global scope, outside of any function, class or user-declared namespace, shall be declared before its use in global scope.`

Comment: Where is it said in the Standard?

Comment: That is given under  `3.4.1 Unqualified name lookup` in `N 3690`

Comment: It is unqualified name lookup